# add post affiliate pro Track (vue frontend)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, affiliate

I have this tacking code that is working good with php

```
    <script type="text/javascript" id="pap_x2s6df8d" src="https://www.linkaraby.com/scripts/2xjh8l8dq0"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
PostAffTracker.setAccountId('cc4af062');
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$total = 0; 
$pid ""; 
foreach ($products as $item) { 
$total += $item['total'];
 $pid .= $item['product_id']. ";"; 
$i++; }
echo "var sale = PostAffTracker.createSale();";
echo "sale.setTotalCost('". $total ."');"; 
echo "sale.setProductID('". $pid ."');"; 
echo "sale.setOrderID('". $order_id ."');"; 
echo "sale.setCoupon('". $Coupon_Code ."');"
?>
PostAffTracker.register(); </script>
```

but my frontend is vue I did something like this

1-load javascript link on page mounted

```
mounted() {
        let linkAraby = document.createElement('script')
        linkAraby.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.linkaraby.com/scripts/2xjh8l8dq0')
        linkAraby.setAttribute('id', 'pap_x2s6df8d');
        linkAraby.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        document.head.appendChild(linkAraby);


    },
```

2- add new method for handle create Sale

```
linkArabys(){
            window.PostAffTracker.setAccountId('cc4af062');
            let sale = window.PostAffTracker.createSale();
            sale.setTotalCost('55');
            sale.setProductID('0');
            sale.setOrderID('7');
            sale.setCoupon('0')
            window.PostAffTracker.register();
          }
```

Is this method correct or is there another way to add the tracking code(post affiliate pro) to the sites designed by vue

Answer (score 0):

```
linkArabys(){
            window.PostAffTracker.setAccountId(this.settings.link_araby_accountid.toString());
            window.sale = window.PostAffTracker.createSale();
            window.sale.setTotalCost((this.settings.price_with_vat == 1)  ? (this.order_data.sub_total - this.order_data.discount + this.payment_form.tax) : this.order_data.sub_total);
            window.sale.setProductID('0');
            window.sale.setOrderID(this.order_data.code);
            window.sale.setCoupon('0')
            window.PostAffTracker.register();
          }
```

this working for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).